# how to pul data from a .csv web file and store to a variable with the option to store it later in a database

Tags: python

I'm start to learn python and need your help. I program in my last time only with Matlab.

I want to pul as a while loop data form a .csv web file and if the date variable change, append the data to the old and store it in an (cell-)array with the option later to store it in the database.

**So my code in python:**

```
import csv
import urllib.request

url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AGRO.BA,PR15.BA,&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8')) #with the appropriate encoding
data = [row for row in csvfile]
```

**the output is:**
(the data means: tick, value, date, time, change, mean, high, low, value)

**['AGRO.BA', '3.14', '10/28/2015', '4:49pm', '+0.09', '3.05', '3.25', '3.00', '150988']
['BA-C.BA', '115.00', '10/21/2015', '11:41am', '+0.00', '115.00', '115.00', '115.00', '100'] ...**

As I can understand it in matlab, python save data in 2 rows as strings in data.

**1. Question:**
How can I save it in data in cellarrays with different variable types?

**2. Question:**
How can I save the date as an datenum (datenumber)?

**3. Question:**
How can I change the format of time in 24h format without 'am' or 'pm' and so store it as time or double not as string?

**4. Question:**
How can I pul the data in while loop and if the time change, the program load the old stored data(cell-)array and attend the new data to the old data (not overwrite but attend to the old!)?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using matlab, you're using Python. The term "datenum" is not even used in Python. I suggest you start by learning the basics of Python before making assumptions on what's "required" -- your second question looks like exactly this kind of incorrect assumption. Why you need to set "variable types" is also unclear, or what exactly your purpose is with #4. Appending to a list is easy, but who knows if that is what you want, it's not exactly clear.

Comment: Question 4 means: If the last date in the cellarray is not the same date in the new cellarray then attend the new cellarray to the old cellarray.

Comment: What you may need to know (apart from Python itself) is that the module for saving and loading objects (variables) of any type is called pickle

Comment: @nigel222 please give me a example code. import ? pickle?

Comment: you really do need to learn Python. import is part of the language. pickle is the name of a module for loading and saving objects. See the answer.

Comment: The Internet is not here to tutor you for free @Tommy -- if you have no interest in performing a single Google search on your own, you're going to encounter some bad attitude from people.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh. What you're supposed to do if someone posts a pointer like that, is use Google to find documents relating to "Python" and "pickle". Without knowing it's called pickle, it takes a lot longer to find the python documentation for what you need.

However, for the benefit of posterity, here's the absolute basics, as two separate interpreter sessions

Example of saving some Python objects (a dict and a list-structure), in a way that allows the objects to be recreated later

```
 >>> d=dict(a=1,c=3,e=5)
 >>> d
 {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'e': 5}
 >>> L=['hello','goodbye',['a','list','in','a','list']]

 >>> f = open('temp.tmp','wb')  # open a pickle file
 >>> import pickle
 >>> pickle.dump( d, f)  # save d to the pickle file
 >>> pickle.dump( L, f)  # followed by 
 >>> f.close()
```

and exit. What's in the file can now be read back in by another Python program. Note that there are multiple versions of the pickle protocol, so if you want to read in to a different version of Python to the one that did the writing, you may need to find out about the optional `protocol` argument to the pickle functions. That aside, let's read that file ....

```
>>> import pickle 
>>> f=open('temp.tmp','rb')
>>> something=pickle.load(f)
>>> something
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'e': 5}
>>> something2 = pickle.load(f)
>>> something2
['hello', 'goodbye', ['a', 'list', 'in', 'a', 'list']]
>>>
```

You can pickle most sorts of Python objects but not all of them. Lists and dicts and nests of them are fine.